# rspec-puppet unit test for define type using resource

Tags: puppet, rspec-puppet

I have written a user define type which downloads a file using wget and stores in /root. I have used exec type to accomplish this. the code is working well with puppet apply, now when I am trying to write rspec test for the same, i am facing issues and getting failure messages. `Please find the site.pp, download.pp, init_spec.rb file.`

I am new to rspec and puppet and unable to find a solution for this, kindly help with suggestion on how to write the rspec test for this define type.

**manifest/site.pp**

```
$link='https://rpm.nodesource.com/pub_8.x/el/7/x86_64/'
$rpm = 'nodejs-8.0.0-1nodesource.el7.centos.x86_64.rpm'

node_js::download{'execute wget':
                comm=>'/usr/bin/wget',
                url=>"${link}${rpm}",
                path=>'/root',
            }
```

**modules/node_js/manifests/download.pp**

```
define node_js::download($comm=undef,
                         $url=undef,
                         $path=undef){

$validate= "nodejs-8.0.0-1nodesource.el7.centos.x86_64.rpm"

    exec { 'execute wget':
    command => "${comm} ${url}",
        cwd => "${path}",
     unless => "/usr/bin/ls  ${path} | grep ${validate}",

    }
}
```

**rspec test file**

**modules/node_js/spec/defines/init_spec.rb**

```
require 'spec_helper'
describe 'node_js::download', :type => 'define' do

  let(:title) { 'node_js::download' }


  it {
    is_expected.to contain_exec('/usr/bin/wget h*tps://rpm.nodesource.com/pub_8.x/el/7/x86_64/nodejs-8.0.0-1nodesource.el7.centos.x86_64.rpm').with({
         'cwd' => '/root/' ,
    })
  }

end
```

**rspec execution  error display message**

```
[root@puppet node_js]# rspec spec/defines/init_spec.rb
F

Failures:

  1) node_js::download should contain Exec[/usr/bin/wget https://rpm.nodesource.com/pub_8.x/el/7/x86_64/nodejs-8.0.0-1nodesource.el7.centos.x86_64.rpm] with cwd => "/root/"
should contain Exec[/usr/bin/wget h*tps://rpm.nodesource.com/pub_8.x/el/7/x86_64/nodejs-8.0.0-1nodesource.el7.centos.x86_64.rpm] with cwd => "/root/"
     Failure/Error:
       is_expected.to contain_exec('/usr/bin/wget h*tps://rpm.nodesource.com/pub_8.x/el/7/x86_64/nodejs-8.0.0-1nodesource.el7.centos.x86_64.rpm').with({
         'cwd' => '/root/' ,
       })

       expected that the catalogue would contain Exec[/usr/bin/wget https://rpm.nodesource.com/pub_8.x/el/7/x86_64/nodejs-8.0.0-1nodesource.el7.centos.x86_64.rpm]
     # ./spec/defines/init_spec.rb:8:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.69964 seconds (files took 8.81 seconds to load)
1 example, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/defines/init_spec.rb:7 # node_js::download should contain Exec[/usr/bin/wget ht*ps://rpm.nodesource.com/pub_8.x/el/7/x86_64/nodejs-8.0.0-1nodesource.el7.centos.x86_64.rpm] with cwd => "/root/"

[root@puppet node_js]#
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are on the right track.

Here is what you should have in `init_spec.rb`:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe 'node_js::download', :type => 'define' do
  let(:title) { 'node_js::download' }
  let(:params) do
    {
      :comm => '/usr/bin/wget',
      :path => '/root/',
      :url  => 'https://rpm.nodesource.com/pub_8.x/el/7/x86_64/nodejs-8.0.0-1nodesource.el7.centos.x86_64.rpm',
    }
  end

  it {
    is_expected.to contain_exec('execute wget').with({
      'command' => '/usr/bin/wget https://rpm.nodesource.com/pub_8.x/el/7/x86_64/nodejs-8.0.0-1nodesource.el7.centos.x86_64.rpm',
      'cwd'     => '/root/',
    })
  }
end
```

You have correctly set the title of the defined-type-under-test using `let(:title) { ... }` but you have not set the input parameters. I added the input parameters that you apparently intended.

Second point is you expected the Exec resource to have a title containing the command, whereas the actual title is going to be `execute wget`, per what you have in `download.pp`.

Otherwise, it looks good.

Comment: The code worked as per the changes suggested. Thank you Alex